# Netbeans using python platform instead of jython

Tags: python, netbeans, plugins

I want to use python within netBeans IDE.

I downloaded the plugin from Tool -> Plugins , But the problem is I can't change the platform used when I want to create python project.

The python platform is set to "Jython 2.7.0", and when I try to use downloaded python platform using Manage-> new 
it gives me "Invalid Python Type".

Is there anyway to use Python platform instead of Jython on netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to use Python platform instead of Jython on netbeans?

Yes, there is Python support available for NetBeans IDE 8.0.2.

The plugin detail page for Python is [Python4NetBeans802 - plugin detail](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56795?show=true).

There is also a blog published on Oracle by Geertjan's Blog on Random NetBeans Stuff :- [Python in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81). Follow the steps as mentioned in the blog.

I'd just like to add that the blog was written on Dec 10, 2014. Maybe, it still works perfectly and is helpful. Give it a try.

Comment: I did what you mentioned exactly, you could do that by downloading a plugin manually or from tools-> plugins , but the problem is the default used platform is jython, and I can't set python due to the error mentioned on the question.

Comment: @Aladdin - I asked you to watch the video posted on the blog, please re-confirm after watching as done in the blog.